# battery optimization not available for some applications. how it could be?

Tags: android, android-doze, android-appstandby

i want to disable battery optimization for my application. i know that showing dialog with REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS is the way that user can disable that. but in some apps like QK SMS, it's fully disabled even in battery settings. how can i fully disable battery optimize for my application like that?

[image of qksms in system battery optimization settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr0LR.png)

Comment: Is QKSMS your current default SMS app? The default app will have optimizations disabled automatically.

Comment: yeah. that's right so this is because the app has been selected as default app. i tested with other sms apps and they were the same when select them as default

Comment: @Reza Zarchi were you able to find any way of disabling battery optimization that will show as not available instead of not optimized in setting.

Comment: @MRamzan this message is shown when you use SMS handler and user set your app as default SMS app

Comment: @MikeM. I've seen some apps like some file sharing apps also have the optimizations automatically disabled. How come?

Comment: @RezaZarchi Were you able to achieve it? I've seen some apps like some file sharing apps also have the optimizations automatically disabled. How come?

Comment: SMS apps are exempt from battery optimization when they utilize an SMS handler and the user designates the app as the primary SMS application on their device. There may be additional exclusion rules for different types of applications. For instance, the default file permission rules in recent Android versions may not provide sufficient accessibility for file manager applications. As a result, developers must submit their app to Google to obtain an exclusion from these Android limitations. As a result, Battery optimization may also be excluded from those apps.